# How to receive subscription callbacks while a loop is running?

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Software: python, ros2 (foxy)

I have a main loop in my node, and I would also still like to receive updates from a subscription - however, I can't quite figure out how to make it work. I tried to play around with the `executor` but that didn't go quite right... Any help or pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Simple example, starting with the simple subscriber:

```
  # subscriber
  import rclpy
  from rclpy.node import Node
  from std_msgs.msg import String
  
  class MinimalSubscriber(Node):
    def __init__(self):
      super().__init__('minimal_subscriber')
      self.subscription = self.create_subscription(
          String,
          'topic',
          self.listener_callback,
          10)
  
      self.run_loop()
  
    def run_loop(self):
      while True:
        pass
  
  
    def listener_callback(self, msg):
      self.get_logger().info('I heard: "%s"' % msg.data)
  
  
  def main(args=None):
    rclpy.init(args=args)
  
    minimal_subscriber = MinimalSubscriber()
  
    rclpy.spin(minimal_subscriber)
  
    minimal_subscriber.destroy_node()
    rclpy.shutdown()
  
  
  if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The publisher:

```
  # publisher
  import rclpy
  from rclpy.node import Node
  from std_msgs.msg import String
  
  
  class MinimalPublisher(Node):
    def __init__(self):
      super().__init__('minimal_publisher')
      self.publisher_ = self.create_publisher(String, 'topic', 10) 
      timer_period = 0.5  # seconds
      self.timer = self.create_timer(timer_period, self.timer_callback)
      self.i = 0 
  
    def timer_callback(self):
      msg = String()
      msg.data = 'Hello World: %d' % self.i
      self.publisher_.publish(msg)
      self.get_logger().info('Publishing: "%s"' % msg.data)
      self.i += 1
  
  def main(args=None):
    rclpy.init(args=args)
  
    minimal_publisher = MinimalPublisher()
  
    rclpy.spin(minimal_publisher)
  
    minimal_publisher.destroy_node()
    rclpy.shutdown()
  
  
  if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/401009/how-to-receive-subscription-callbacks-while-a-loop-is-running?/) by [printf42](https://answers.ros.org/users/95929/printf42/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2022-05-20

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) on 2022-05-20**:
What exactly is happening in your main loop? Maybe this can be solved with async callbacks?

**Comment by [printf42](https://answers.ros.org/users/95929/printf42/) on 2022-05-20**:
Hi thanks for your comment, I know only of async callbacks in javascript -- would like to know more about what you mean.

The loop is running a webcam class which is classifying data...

**Comment by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) on 2022-05-23**:
This topic and the tutorial there: https://discourse.ros.org/t/how-to-use-callback-groups-in-ros2/25255 is really helpful for understanding SingleThreadedExecutors (default) and MultiThreadedExecutors in ROS2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Edit; in the original answer I did no understand the question. The `run()` function includes a in definetly runnjng while loop, so the object creation never completes since the function is executed in constructor. Instead of blocking while loop you may want to use timer callback for periodic loops. Below is an example;

```
import rclpy
import rclpy.node
import rclpy.qos

from geometry_msgs.msg import Point


class ROS2Pub(rclpy.node.Node):

    def __init__(self, *args):
        super(ROS2Pub, self).__init__("topic_pub")
        self.my_pub = self.create_publisher(
            Point, "points", rclpy.qos.qos_profile_sensor_data)
        self.timer = self.create_timer(0.1, self.timer_callback)
        self.get_logger().info("Started the node")

    def timer_callback(self):
        msg = Point()
        msg.x = 10.0
        self.my_pub.publish(msg)
        self.get_logger().info("Published a point with x of %s" % msg.x)


def main():
    rclpy.init()
    node = ROS2Pub()
    rclpy.spin(node)
    rclpy.shutdown()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

---

Originally posted by [Fetullah Atas](https://answers.ros.org/users/32821/fetullah-atas/) with karma: 819 on 2022-05-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [printf42](https://answers.ros.org/users/95929/printf42/) on 2022-05-20**:
Thanks for your comment -- unfortunately this doesn't work as `listener_callback`  is still not being called while the loop is active...

**Comment by [Fetullah Atas](https://answers.ros.org/users/32821/fetullah-atas/) on 2022-05-20**:
I did not understand your question. You are calling self.run_loop() in constructor, your code stucks there, so the node never gets spinned hence no callback is executed.

**Comment by [printf42](https://answers.ros.org/users/95929/printf42/) on 2022-05-20**:
Any ideas how I can make it work? I can call `rclpy.spin_once(self)` inside the loop - however that will only block until a callback comes in... It seems it can be solved with the help of the `executor` however, I haven't quite figured out how to do that yet...

Edit: so I can do `rclpy.spin_once(self, timeout_sec=0.001)` for example - but this really seems like a duct tape solution... There must be a more elegant way of doing this...

**Comment by [Fetullah Atas](https://answers.ros.org/users/32821/fetullah-atas/) on 2022-05-22**:
Instead of doing a while loop you can use a timer callback, see an example [here](https://github.com/NMBURobotics/ros2_python_demos/blob/main/ros2_demo_python_nodes/ros2_demo_python_nodes/topic_pub.py)

**Comment by [printf42](https://answers.ros.org/users/95929/printf42/) on 2022-05-23**:
Please introduce this as an answer and I will accep it. Thank you.

**Comment by [Fetullah Atas](https://answers.ros.org/users/32821/fetullah-atas/) on 2022-05-23**:
I edited the answer